# wp-cli incorrectly believes a plugin is currently installed

Tags: wp-cli

I ran  `wp plugin deactivate woocommerce --uninstall` and it did so successfully. I verified with `#ls wp-content/plugins`  the `woocommerce` folder no longer exists.

**Problem:**
when I run `wp plugin install woocommerce --activate` the command returns:

```
Warning: woocommerce: Plugin already installed.
Warning: The 'woocommerce' plugin could not be found.
Success: Plugin already installed.
```

**Question:**
What is the most efficient command line way to repair this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try `wp plugin delete woocommerce`, then reinstalling it.